# passing a variable into archive.php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site, that has two blogs, "Latest News" and "Blog". Each have their own individual sidebars with recent posts, categories and archives.

All is fine except for the archives. I hacked a plugin called "Better Archives Widget" to call up seperate archive listings based on whether I was in "Latest News" or "Blog". While this works fine for the listing in the sidebar, once I click on a date it naturally takes me to archives.php and lists all the posts from all categories.

Archives.php also loads the "Latest News" sidebar, and "Latest news" breadcrumbs even when I click from the blog section. This is understandable as Ive no way of distinguishing between whether im coming from the Latest News or Blog.

The only way I can think of fixing this is by passing a variable into Archives.php based on whether I came from the blog or Latest News section. Once Im in archives.php and have a variable with either of 2 values, I could fix all my other issues (like loading a different sidebar, loading different breadcrumbs, and loading certain posts based on certain categories).

So Im wondering how to pass this information in based on what page I came from.

I use `get_month_link` to get into the archive.

Im not sure what code to include as there would be alot it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I used a query string and the `$_GET` variable in the end to distinguish between the blog and the news.